# Why my python code is displacing the actual location of the data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
import copy
import string
import random


def random_alphanumeric(length, hyphen_interval=4):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    random_value = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return '-'.join(random_value[i:i + hyphen_interval] for i in range(0, len(random_value), hyphen_interval))


# Correct the engine parameter for reading an Excel file
df = pd.read_excel("<path_to>nu_1_test.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

# Find the index where the 'place' string divides the two sets of data
place_index = df.index[df.iloc[:, 0] == 'abc___cdoc'].tolist()

# Check if the 'place' string is found and there is data after it
if place_index and place_index[0] < len(df) - 1:
    # Get the data after the 'place' string
    data_after_place = df.iloc[place_index[0] + 1:].dropna(axis=1, how='all')

    # Assuming 'data_after_place' contains the correct data including the column names as the first row
    # Set the first row as the header
    data_after_place.columns = data_after_place.iloc[0]

    # Drop the first row as it's now set as the header
    data_after_place = data_after_place[1:]

    columns = data_after_place.columns

    updated_rows = []

    for index, row in data_after_place.iterrows():
        updated_rows.append(dict(row))
        if row['Value'] != 0:
            new_row = dict(row)
            new_row['Value'] = -row['Value']
            new_row['ID'] = random_alphanumeric(16, hyphen_interval=4)
            new_row['GLA'] = '2100'

            for col in data_after_place.columns:
                if col not in ['ID', 'Comp', 'Line', 'GLA', 'Val', 'desc', 'Jour', 'D4']:
                    new_row[col] = row.get(col, '')
            # df.loc[index + place_index[0] + 1] = new_row
            updated_rows.append(new_row)
            # df.loc[index + place_index[0] + 1] = new_row

            # df = pd.DataFrame(updated_rows)
    df = pd.concat(
        [df.iloc[:place_index[0] + 1], pd.DataFrame(updated_rows), df.iloc[place_index[0] + 1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(updated_rows)

    # Save the modified data to a new Excel file
    df.to_excel('data_after_place_modified.xlsx', index=False)
else:
    print("No data found after the 'place' string or 'place' is not in the CSV.")
```

The processing of the data is happening as per the requirement. But after the data processing the data is inserted in cells near the 1st set of column header. But in actual the original location of the data should be retained. The processed file screenshot attached-- `data_after_place_modified`). I have also attached the actual file screenshot on which the python program has to be run(nu_1_test).the difference could be seen clearly.

Please suggest, I have been scratching my head for 2 days now without much success.

[image]
[image]

I have asked the question before, but didn't get any suggestion. So, I have come to a position where I could ask for suggestion on new issue.[previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77831167/why-is-the-python-code-is-not-able-to-process-table-in-an-excel-file?noredirect=1#comment137222347_77831167)